# Excel UDF to sum cells having a specific background color

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to Sum up total of cells having a specific background color.

Followed this tutorial here: https://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-cells-based-on-background-color/

When trying to implement the following UDF, I get a syntax error on line 3 (starting with *Dim ColIndex*):

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then cSum = WorksheetFunction.SUM(cl, cSum)
End If
Next cl SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```

Does anyone has an idea how what is wrong with the UDF?

MS Office version: MS Office Professional Plus 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: Split that into two lines starting after the word `Integer`

Comment: Unfortunately that website looks slightly sketch based on the quality of that code snippet.

Comment: Thanks! Needed to split again another line and remove the End If. 
The only remaining problem now, is that the sum doesn't get updated, when I change the background color of a cell. It only works when I execute it, but does not refresh the sum / total on changing cell background color of a new cell, to the color in the formula.

Comment: @ZelelB Changing the formatting does not cause a calculation.  This will never update based on a change to the format of a cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner Isn't there any solution to achieve that in Excel?

Comment: There is no trigger or API that will do that.  You can make the UDF Volatile so that any change that would cause a recalc would recalc the UDF.  But again only changing the format will not do that.  Some cell will need to be kicked into edit then out again to calc, or the calc forced through F9.

Comment: It's do-able with the help of the commandbars onupdate event

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some of the line-ends

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer 
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
    If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then 
        cSum = WorksheetFunction.SUM(cl, cSum)
    End If
Next cl 
SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```